# How to start an activity from fragment in android?

Tags: java, android, android-fragments, android-volley

I want to have one activity and use fragment when click fragment button change activity to second activity

Example: in login activity I click register... If create user change activity to main and finish login activity...

This my fragment code:

```
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_register, container, false);
    edUsername = view.findViewById(R.id.edUser);
    edUserEmail = view.findViewById(R.id.edEmail);
    edUserPhone = view.findViewById(R.id.edPass);
    edUserPassword = view.findViewById(R.id.edPassword);
    btnLogin = view.findViewById(R.id.btnLogin);
    btnRegister = view.findViewById(R.id.btnRegister);

    btnRegister.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            final ProgressDialog loader = ProgressDialog.show(getContext(),
                    "Inserting...", "please wait",
                    false, false);


            StringRequest request = new StringRequest(Request.Method.POST, Config.register_api,
                    new Response.Listener<String>() {
                        @Override
                        public void onResponse(String response) {
                            if (response.equals("a user with same information existing")) {
                                loader.dismiss();
                                Toast.makeText(getContext(), response, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                            }else {
                                loader.dismiss();
                                Toast.makeText(getContext(), response, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                            }
                        }
                    }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
                @Override
                public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                    Toast.makeText(getContext(), error.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    loader.dismiss();
                }
            }) {
                @Override
                protected Map<String, String> getParams() {
                    Map<String, String> params = new HashMap<>();
                    params.put("username", edUsername.getText().toString().trim());
                    params.put("userphone", edUserPhone.getText().toString().trim());
                    params.put("useremail", edUserEmail.getText().toString().trim());
                    params.put("userpassword", edUserPassword.getText().toString().trim());

                    return params;
                }
            };

            RequestQueue requestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(getContext());
            requestQueue.add(request);
        }
    });

    btnLogin.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            
        }
    });
    return view;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to start new `Activity` from `Fragment` you can use:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(getActivity(), NewActivity.class); // creating new intent
startActivity(); // starting new activity with intent
getActivity().finish(); // finish current activity
```

Just insert this in your code where you want to start new activity.

If you want to start new `Activity` from another `Activity` use this:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(CurrentActivity.this, NewActivity.class);
startActivity();
finish();
```